# How can I verify the trust between 2 domains in Windows Server 2008R2 Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

How can I verify the trust between 2 domains in Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory? Is there a tool for it? Maybe a snap-in or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using the Windows interface**

Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts.

In the console tree, right-click the domain that contains the trust that you want to validate, and then click Properties.

On the Trusts tab, under either Domains trusted by this domain (outgoing trusts) or Domains that trust this domain (incoming trusts), click the trust to be validated, and then click Properties.

Click Validate.

Click Yes, validate the incoming trust.

**Using the command line**

Open a Command Prompt.

Type the following command, and then press ENTER:

```
netdom trust TrustingDomainName /d: TrustedDomainName /verify
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the same utility that is used to create the trust.

- Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts
- Open the properties of the domain that contains the trust you are
  looking to verify
- Under the trusts tab, select the trust and select
  properties
- Click the validate button

For a more detailed steps, please refer to the [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737447%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) article that details this process.