# Cross-Realm trust verify failed with 'netdom' command

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, kerberos, mitkerberos

**Question 1:**

1. Am having my ActiveDirectory in Windowsserver 2012 machine - its domain name is *AD-DEMO.LOCAL*
2. Kerberos admin-server is in another Ubuntu machine - its realm KERBEROS.COM
3. Added trust in 'Active Directory Domains and Trusts'.
4. Properties set for the trust realm in AD are,

   - transitive and two-way checking.
5. Tried to verify the cross-realm trusts with the following "netdom" command,

   **"netdom trust KERBEROS.COM /d:AD-DEMO.LOCAL /verify"**

   And got this exception  **"The command failed to complete successfully"**

**Question 2:**

To resolve this did a search and found these links ( [Link 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/509965/how-can-i-verify-the-trust-between-2-domains-in-windows-server-2008r2-active-dir) and [Link 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737447(v=ws.10).aspx));

From the info of these two links, I tried to enable validate property for the domains added. But I didnt find any properties like Validate in my AD Domains and trusts window.

Please suggest where I go wrong,

Comment: Per your Link 2: "You can verify trusts for shortcut, external, and forest trusts but not realm trusts."

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using the `netdom trust /verify` command, you would need to specify administrative credentials (Domain Admin/Enterprise Admin) for both domains using the switches `/PasswordO:`, `/UserO:`, `/PasswordD:` and `/UserD:`

Full Syntax:

```
netdom trust <TrustingDomainName> {/d: | /domain:} <TrustedDomainName> [{/ud: | /userd:}[<Domain>\]<User> [{/pd: | /passwordd:}{<Password>|*}] [{/uo: | /usero:}<User>] [{/po: | /passwordo:}{<Password>|*}] [/verify] [/reset] [/passwordt:<NewRealmTrustPassword>] [/add [/realm]] [/remove [/force]] [/twoway] [/kerberos] [/transitive[:{YES|NO}]] [/oneside:{TRUSTED | TRUSTING}] [/force] [/quarantine[:{YES | NO}]] [/namesuffixes:<TrustName> [/togglesuffix:#]] [/EnableSIDHistory] [/ForestTRANsitive] [/SelectiveAUTH][/AddTLN][/AddTLNEX][/RemoveTLN] [/RemoveTLNEX][/SecurePasswordPrompt] [/EnableTgtDelegation] [{/help | /?}]
```

Reference: [Netdom trust](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835085.aspx)

**To verify a trust using the Windows interface**

1. Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts. To open Active Directory
   Domains and Trusts, click Start , click Administrative Tools , and
   then click Active Directory Domains and Trusts .
2. To open Active Directory Domains and Trusts in Windows Server® 2012,
   click Start , type domain.msc .
3. In the console tree, right-click the domain that contains the trust
   that you want to verify, and then click Properties .
4. On the Trusts tab, under either Domains trusted by this domain
   (outgoing trusts) or Domains that trust this domain (incoming
   trusts) , click the trust to be verified, and then click Properties
   .
5. Click Validate .
6. Do one of the following, and then click OK :

   - Click No, do not validate the incoming trust. If you select this option, we recommend that you repeat this procedure for the reciprocal domain.
   - Click Yes, validate the incoming trust. If you select this option, you must type a user account and password with administrative credentials for the reciprocal domain.

Reference: [Verify a trust](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753821.aspx)